# Using terraform vsphere resource to set network_interface label

Tags: terraform, vsphere

Is there a way to use the vsphere data sources to set the network_interface label when creating a vm instance?

The docs seem to state you can only use names. The data sources export only ids.

I've put what I was thinking below, but not sure it would work. I'm new to this tbh.

```
data "vsphere_distributed_virtual_switch" "dvs" {
  name          = "my_dvs"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.datacenter.id}"
}

data "vsphere_network" "dgp" {
  name          = "my_dgp"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.datacenter.id}"
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "linux_box" {
  ...
  network_interface {
    label = "${data.vsphere_network.dvs.id}/${data.vsphere_network.dgp.id}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run a test case to prove it.

Save below codes to `data.tf`

```
data "vsphere_datacenter" "datacenter" {
  name = "dc1"
}

data "vsphere_distributed_virtual_switch" "dvs" {
  name          = "my_dvs"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.datacenter.id}"
}

data "vsphere_network" "dgp" {
  name          = "my_dgp"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.datacenter.id}"
}
```

run `terraform plan` and `terraform apply`. **Since there is no resource create/destroy, it is safe to run it.**

After run `terraform apply`, it will generate a file `terraform.tfstate`, view this file if the id is the name you are looking for.

If it is, the code you wrote is correct.

Comment: that's a little big different than what I'm looking for unfortunately. If it gives me back the name as the id and I had to lookup the id by name, I essentially am using the data source for no reason. I'll be testing to see if the id can be used in the provider instead

Comment: Then what part you are unknown?

Comment: I guess i was looking for a way to use IDs in the vm resource, since they are a bit more absolute. I've submitted an issue on github and it seems that the vm resource doesn't accept IDs in it's current form, but is being worked on for the new release. So at this point, vsphere data sources are incompatible with the vm resource. thanks for taking the time!